# retrieve the text encoded with a wrong Encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, character-encoding, arabic

I have a text file exported from a Foxpro (Dos-based) program, but this text contains non-English characters ( arabic [ right to left ] ) and now exported strings are like this "¤“îگüَن" .

is there any way to convert them back to their original values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the data with the proper code page.

```
public static string ReadFile(string path, int codepage)
{
    return Encoding.GetEncoding(codepage)
        .GetString(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
}
```

Invoke the function with the right code page ID, for MS-DOS Arabic it should be "708", for a complete list you can start on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page).

```
string content = ReadFile(@"c:\test.txt", 708);
```

Solution with look-up table to translate from unsupported encodings (mapping is required only for charactes > 127):

```
public static string ReadFile(string path, byte[] translationTable, int codepage)
{
    byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    for (int i=0; i < content.Length; ++i)
    {
        byte value = content[i];
        if (value > 127)
            content[i] = translationTable[value - 128];
    }

    return Encoding.GetEncoding(codepage)
        .GetString(content);
}
```

An example of translation table:

```
Index    Original (IS)    Translated (1256)
...
13       141              194
...
```

Comment: the code page is not correct . where can I find a list of code pages ?

Comment: I figured out that the encoding is a custom one called IranSystem , created to be used for FARSI ( persian ) language .                     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_System_encoding_standard

Comment: of course you haven't , it was just used in IRAN . is it possible to use your solution with this encoding ?

Comment: @reza no, the cp1256 is not compatible with that encoding. A possible (but time consuming) solution could be to do a custom look-up table to translate from IranSystem to 1256 and then decode data from it (small example added).

Comment: it's working great :) , but there is another problem ,It seems that the space between words are lost ( backspace ) I mean instead of e.g : hello world , I have helloworld ( but in arabic )

Comment: Space (#32) shouldn't be touched, is there some character replaced with backspace (#127)?